# ORACLE SQL Selecting column twice in same statement

Tags: oracle

I have searched endlessly but have yet to find a concise answer to this question.

How can I go about selecting the same column from the same table twice in a SELECT statement with different conditions applied in the WHERE clause?

Such that I may be able to generate results which filter the queried column into two columns of output.

Thanks for your time.

What I have thus far, revised for anonymity:

```
SELECT C_OPERATOR AS "ID", C_OPERATORLOCALE AS "LOCALE", SUM(C_PRODUCTIONCOUNT) AS "PRODUCTION", C_OPERATOR AS "ID 2"

FROM TABLE1

WHERE C_STARTTIME BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 13) + 1380/1440 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE -6) +1379/1440
AND C_OPERATOR <  '200000'

GROUP BY C_OPERATOR, C_OPERATORLOCALE

ORDER BY C_OPERATORLOCALE
```

In the `SELECT` statement I specify c_operator twice which obviously returns the results in two columns exactly the same...

Comment: Could you provide an example of the data and what you have tried already ? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I wonder if you're after something like `select case when col1 = 'some val 1' then 'some result 1' when col1 = 'some val 2' then 'some result 2' end, .... `? Without more information, it's difficult to say.

Comment: See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b643e/5).

Comment: 'C_STARTTIME BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 13) + 1380/1440 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE -6) +1379/1440' ==>this for first C_OPERATOR statement and 'C_OPERATOR <  '200000' ' ==>> this is for  second C_OPERATOR statement ??

Comment: C_STARTTIME applies to both and 'c_operator < '200000'' applies to both in its current state.  Ideally I would like a way use 'c_operator < '200000'' on c_operator as "ID" and add 'c_operator > '199999'' for c_operator as "ID2"

Comment: If you want a great answer to this, you're really going to need to provide some example input data and output results.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table like

```
create table Test (id number, color varchar2(20));

1, 'red'
2, 'green'
3, 'yellow'
4, 'red'
```

you can simply select the column twice:

```
select t1.id,
       case when t1.color = 'red'   then 'yes' else 'no' end as red,
       case when t1.color = 'green' then 'yes' else 'no' end as green
  from Test t1
```

or you can use a join on the same table, if you need a more complex where clause.

```
select t1.id,
       case when t1.color = 'red'   then 'yes' else 'no' end as red,
       case when t2.color = 'green' then 'yes' else 'no' end as green
  from Test t1 
  join Test t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

both will give you the same result:

```
id  red green
1   yes no
2   no  yes
3   no  no
4   yes no
```

In this case joining will need more resources. Joining the table twice may be faster with complex where clauses, when oracle can use multiple indexes.

Comment: In this case, I have a table which has distinct IDs in every row of C_OPERATOR.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally I would like a way use 'c_operator < '200000'' on c_operator as "ID" and add 'c_operator > '199999'' for c_operator as "ID2"

As @boneist said in a comment, it sounds like you are just looking for [a case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions004.htm#SQLRF20037).

If you have sample data like:

```
C_OPERATOR C_OPERATORLOCALE C_PRODUCTIONCOUNT C_STARTTIM
---------- ---------------- ----------------- ----------
    199998 Europe/London                    1 2017-07-29
    199998 Europe/London                    2 2017-07-29
    199998 America/New York                 3 2017-07-29
    199999 Europe/London                    4 2017-07-29
    200000 Europe/London                    5 2017-07-29
    200001 Europe/London                    6 2017-07-29
```

then something like this:

```
select case when c_operator < 200000 then c_operator end as id,
  c_operatorlocale as locale,
  sum(c_productioncount) as production,
  case when c_operator > 199999 then c_operator end as id_2
from table1
where c_starttime between trunc(sysdate - 13) + 1380/1440 and trunc(sysdate -6) +1379/1440
group by c_operator, c_operatorlocale
order by c_operatorlocale;
```

will produce:

```
        ID LOCALE           PRODUCTION       ID_2
---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
    199998 America/New York          3           
    199998 Europe/London             3           
    199999 Europe/London             4           
           Europe/London             5     200000
           Europe/London             6     200001
```

Notice that there is no restriction on the `c_operator` value in the `where` clause - all rows in the date range are aggregated, with the case expressions putting the operator value into the appropriate ID column.

Answer (score -1):

Like OP said:

> Ideally I would like a way use 'c_operator < '200000'' on c_operator
>   as "ID" and add 'c_operator > '199999'' for c_operator as "ID2"

So, you need something like this:

```
SELECT C_OPERATOR AS "ID", 
       C_OPERATORLOCALE AS "LOCALE", 
       SUM(C_PRODUCTIONCOUNT) AS "PRODUCTION", 
       case when C_OPERATOR > '199999' then C_OPERATOR else NULL end AS "ID 2"
FROM TABLE1
WHERE C_STARTTIME BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - 13) + 1380/1440 AND TRUNC(SYSDATE -6) +1379/1440
AND C_OPERATOR < '200000'
GROUP BY C_OPERATOR, C_OPERATORLOCALE
ORDER BY C_OPERATORLOCALE
```

Comment: There is not any case for "C_OPERATOR > '199999' " becasue of "... where C_OPERATOR < '200000' "

Comment: @mehmet sahin  199999.5